# Abstract class for common DI throws error on injecting Store<State>

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store

I have a **LoginCommon** class that uses **Injector** to inject all common dependencies into multiple login components. This approach works for all dependencies except for the **Store** service (**@ngrx/store**).
When trying to inject **Store** using this technique I get a **runtime error** that is as follows:

```
Error: Token must be defined!
```

This error looks like something basic in dependency injection, what am I missing?

The **LoginCommon** class looks as follows:

```
export class LoginCommon {
protected _loginAuth:LoginAuthService;
protected store: Store<State>;
protected _router:Router;
protected _route:ActivatedRoute;
constructor(
    injector: Injector
) {
        this._loginAuth= injector.get(LoginAuthService);
        this.store = injector.get(this.store);
        this._router = injector.get(Router);
        this._route = injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
    }
}
```

The **State** object for the **Store** service looks as follows:

```
export interface State {
    usermail:string;
    userphone:string;
    user_verification_code:string;
    userpassword:string;
}
```

The **extending class** constructor looks as follows:

```
export class LoginWithPasswordComponent extends LoginCommon {
...
    constructor(
        public injector: Injector
    ) {
        super(injector);
    }
...
}
```

**NOTE!** When commenting out the Store injection from the **LoginCommon** class, and adding it as usual to the **LoginWithPasswordComponent** constructor everything works fine.

Comment: have you initialized `store` in the root module?

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake on my bvehalf.
Was passing a veriable type declaration instead of the service instance.

```
this.store = injector.get(this.store);
```

Should be

```
this.store = injector.get(Store);
```

Changing to the above solved this problem